# Why do Emerald Ash Borers only infest Ash trees

Tags: trees

I have read the types of trees that EAB is attracted to, signs of infestation and how to prevent.  There is a plethora of material on this.  An excerpt from [Wikipedia on the EAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald_ash_borer#Invasiveness):

*Green ash and black ash trees are preferred by emerald ash borer. White ash is also killed rapidly but usually only after all green and black ash trees are eliminated. Blue ash is known to exhibit a higher degree of resistance to emerald ash borer, which is believed to be caused by the high tannin content in the leaves making the foliage unpalatable to the insect.*

However, no one seems to answer the question of **why Ash trees**?  What is it about Ash trees that the EAB likes, and why don't they appear to attack other tree species?

Comment: The comment in Wikipedia about the blue ash is flat-out wrong, as the borers eat the wood, not the leaves. Latest research indicates that resistant trees produce chemicals that kill the larvae when they feed on the cambial layer of wood. This has nothing to do with tannins. Blue ash does indeed appear to be the most resistant of North American ash trees, but still suffers mortality greater than 55%.

Comment: @Jurp - Thank you for your comments, but they do eat the leaves according to Kansas State University https://www.atchison.k-state.edu/EAB%20frequently_asked_questions.pdf

Comment: @Jurp Ah, I see, larvae eat the tissue under the bark, adults eat the leaves.

Comment: The tannin in the leaves won't affect the larvae, so tannin is, according to other researchers, NOT the reason blue ash is more resistant than the other species.

Comment: @Jurp I have edited my post and removed the tannin speculation.